# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after Dockerfile build

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

I am just trying to get a demo java spring boot app to run on Google Cloud Run. I am new to Docker and Maven.

I am using a Github repository with a workflow file/Github actions to build the docker and upload it to google container registry.

When I try running the container in Cloud Run I get a ClassNotFound exception so I'm a bit confused on what's going on and how to get my src classes into the docker and such.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyDemoApplication
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

I've been messing around with my Dockerfile trying different things but I always get some sort of error. I'm not quite understanding it.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.3 AS maven

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=maven /usr/src/app/target/my-demo-app.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","my-demo-app.jar"]
```

when I run "COPY . ." shouldnt that copy everything from the repo to the docker, why cant it get the source classes?

Here is my pom.xml for Maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javademowithmaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JavaDemoWithMaven</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>my-demo-app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                             <mainClass>com.example.JavaDemoWithMavenApplication</mainClass>
                             <layout>JAR</layout>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong??
?

Comment: Can you post the full  Exception? Your COPY works as expected. Is the build successful or do you get an error there as well?

Comment: I just added the full exception. It is not finding MyDemoApplication which is just a class that is in my src folder. It is labeled with @SpringBootApplication and just has a basic main function and a RestController inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured it out.

I checked my .gitignore file and realized that my target directories were listed in there, causing them to not be loaded in.